# Session with Value Null Java/Neo4J

Tags: java, neo4j

Hello i´m having problems in Java Null Pointer Exception in Session

This is my code:

```
public Configs(String uri, String username, String password)
{

    Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, AuthTokens.basic(username, password) );


}
```

.....

```
public Boolean existMachine(){

    machine mach  = new machine();


    try (Session session = driver.session())
    {

}
}
```

And i call the Function in `main(String[] args)`:

```
Configs connections = new Configs("bolt://localhost:7474", "neo4j", "");

if(connections.existMachine().booleanValue() == false)
{
...
}
else{
..
}
```

I´m getting error in:

```
try (Session session = driver.session())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't set drivers as an instance field of your class.

You have to make it available in `existMachine`

Comment: I´m getting Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Unable to process request: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?